# How do I get a persistent pointer to a String?

Tags: c, swift, string, pointers

I found [`String`'s generic instance method `withCString(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1538904-withcstring), but I need to get pointers to multiple strings and don't want to have a bunch of nested closures. For example, let's say that `str1` and `str2` are both `String` instances, `foo` and `bar` are both C struct types, and `do_something` is a C function. Then how do I do something like this?

```
let ptr1 = str1.pointerThatPersistsEvenAfterPassedToFunction
let ptr2 = str2.pointerThatPersistsEvenAfterPassedToFunction
let c_struct1 = foo(ptr1, 1, 2)
let c_struct2 = bar(ptr2, 3, c_struct1)
do_something(c_struct1, c_struct2)
str1.invalidatePersistentPointer
str2.invalidatePersistentPointer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot safely access a Swift `String`'s underlying buffer without using `withCString`.

So you can either use the nested closures which is the safest and most correct way to use the `CString`s or you can use `UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>` and allocate and manage the `CString`s yourself.